# Is this a troll or a bot answering?

Tags: discussion, answers, robots, trolling

This really caught my attention. As you can below this photo, there's user (Maybe a  person or maybe bot) answered the question but it is not answer the question.

[image]

So is this person just a pure troll or a bot want to test us if we have really watch carefully those question and answer?

Comment: This happens quite a lot but they usually get deleted pretty quickly.

Comment: It could be a troll bot. I've seen weirder things.

Comment: Something [like this](https://d1w8cc2yygc27j.cloudfront.net/9049916132270914227/-5720482768110523328.jpg) (sfw), @FrédéricHamidi?

Comment: @Cerbrus, exactly. I like the hair.

Comment: what is that....

Comment: @Cerbrus Tonight I will not be able to sleep.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Probably a troll, but it could just as well be a bot...

Either way, posts like that should be flagged as *"rude or abusive"*.

> [image]